# How to change the path to the database files?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, filepath

I've created the simple program that is connected with one database. The connection with SQL db is perfect. I can insert data now. I use Object Explorer SQL Server.

Now my issue: I cannot use the program if the path to the mdf file isn't "C:/folder/repair.mdf". I want my program to be independent from the C disk, because I should send this program (vs files, etc) to other people.

How can I write the correct path and where can I do that?

Comment: Does your program create the file or do you ship it? You _could_ either use a standard folder like %AppData%/YourProgram/repair.mdf or use a path relative to the .exe. I personally would recommend AppData. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath?view=net-5.0

Comment: When using SQL Server (or any other server-based DB engine for the matter) your program don't handle or even knows the location of the mdf file, that's entirely managed by the server. Your program only choses server/db name/user/password and the server manages the db files.

Comment: If I should use %AppData%, where should I change this text? Because I have found out I can't change this in properties.

Comment: You should use a relative path to the data folder in the csproj project file instead of the full path name including c:\.

Comment: @Nazarii1000, Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to move your db file to other disk and read the correct path.

**First**, please close all the connection about the database.(Execute the following query in Query Editor window )

```
ALTER DATABASE School SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

**Second**, you could copy your db file from the C disk to your project.(Include mdf and ldf file)

**Finally**, we can execute the following c# code to connect to the db file.(I place the db file in project\bin\debug\school.mdf).

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dbpath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+"School.mdf";
            string connstr = string.Format("Data Source=yourdatasource;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;", dbpath);
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            connection.Open();
            string sql = "select * from Student";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Note: The dbpath is a absolute path, which can specify to the corresponding path in different computers.